# Workflow Instance Blocking Calculated Field Update

Tags: workflow, calculated-column

Is it possible that an instance of a workflow can prevent a calculated field from being updated?

My scenario:

SharePoint 2013

Workflow 2010

Calculated field: `(=IF([Dt Prox Contato]<Now(),"Old", "Normal" ))`.

The field receives the correct data, but when the date is exceeded the calculated field is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint updates the value of a calculated field when you save an item OR when you change the calculation in the field setting. A workflow instance can not prevent a calculated field from being updated AFAIK, I've had plenty of instances with workflows running and the calculated fields worked just fine. I guess it might depend on what the workflow is doing.

This post might help: http://sympmarc.com/2009/12/04/how-are-a-sharepoint-lists-calculated-columns-stored-and-rendered/ It explains at which point calculated fields are updated.

Comment: The workflow sends email when the date exceeded

Comment: Unless you are updating the field in the workflow, I doubt it would have any effect on the calculated field! Why not try removing the workflow instance and check if the calculated field is updated?

Comment: I've done it and it did not work, I set the workflow only to manual start and check if it will work

Comment: It did not work. But already used this formula before. I will investigate further...